# Airflow - timing out task without killing DAG

Tags: airflow

I want to set a certain timeout for my `BashOperator` using `execution_timeout`, but I've noticed it raises `AirflowTaskTimeout`.

What I'm looking for is to execute a certain behavior in the case of a timeout and then continue the DAG from the next task. I could use bash `timeout`, but I'm looking for internal Airflow support for the same functionality.

Does Airflow support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow has a concept of [Trigger Rules](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules). You can pass `trigger_rule=one_failed` or `trigger_rule=all_done` to the next task. You can have 2 tasks that are directly dependent on the first task.

For example:

```
task_a >> task_b (trigger_rule='all_success') >> task_d (trigger_rule='one_success')
task_a >> task_c (trigger_rule='all_failed') >> task_d (trigger_rule='one_success')
```

From the docs:

All operators have a `trigger_rule` argument which defines the rule by which the generated task get triggered. The default value for `trigger_rule` is `all_success` and can be defined as “trigger this task when all directly upstream tasks have succeeded”. All other rules described here are based on direct parent tasks and are values that can be passed to any operator while creating tasks:

- `all_success`: (default) all parents have succeeded
- `all_failed`: all parents are in a failed or upstream_failed state
- `all_done`: all parents are done with their execution
- `one_failed`: fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does not wait for all parents to be done
- `one_success`: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done
- `none_failed`: all parents have not failed (failed or upstream_failed) i.e. all parents have succeeded or been skipped
- `dummy`: dependencies are just for show, trigger at will

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful! is there a way to know if the upstream task timed out or "just" failed?

Comment: Glad that you found that useful. Can you upvote or accept it as the answer, please to help the future visitors?

Regarding the other thing, a timed-out task will be marked as failed, so, unfortunately, we don't have that out-of-the-box.